# PHP: What's wrong with my foreach?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

My `foreach` continuously echo's the first condition of my `if` statement and it's not making any sense to me.

If you look inside the `foreach` in the first snippet you'll see an `if` that checks if the `$field === id || image_id`. Every iteration of the `foreach` spits out the `Im and ID: $field => $type <br>` condition even when there is not a single index called `id` or `image_id`. What gives?

### This is the entire method

```
  protected function create_db_table(string $table, array $fields) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."$table";
    $table_charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $field_names = [];
    $check_id = array_key_exists('id', $fields)  ? 'id' : 'image_id';

    foreach ($fields as $field => $type) {
      if ($field === 'id' || 'image_id') {
        echo "Im an ID: $field => $type <br>";
        $field_names[] = "$field $type UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT";
      } else {
          echo "Im NOT and ID: $field => $type <br>";
          $field_names[] = "$field $type";
      }
    }

    $field_names = join(",\n", $field_names);

    // echo "<h1>$field_names</h1>";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
            $field_names,
            PRIMARY KEY  ($check_id)
            ) $table_charset;";

    require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

    dbDelta($sql);
  }
```

### This is how I'm calling it

```
function activation_methods() {
  $slider_settings = new SliderSettings;
  $slider_settings_fields = [
    'id'                => 'int(9)',
    'transition_time'   => 'int(9)',
    'loop_carousel'     => 'tinytext',
    'stop_on_hover'     => 'tinytext',
    'reverse_order'     => 'tinytext',
    'navigation_arrows' => 'tinytext',
    'show_pagination'   => 'tinytext'
  ];

  $slider_images = new SliderImages;
  $slider_images_fields = [
    'image_id'    => 'int(9)',
    'carousel_id' => 'int(9)',
    'image_url'   => 'text'
  ];

  $slider_settings->create_db('bb_slidersettings', $slider_settings_fields);
  $slider_images->create_db('bb_sliderimages', $slider_images_fields);
}
activation_methods();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$field === 'id' || 'image_id'` should be:

`$field === 'id' || $field === 'image_id'`.

Or even shorter: `in_array($field, ['id', 'image_id'])`.

---

`$field === 'id' || 'image_id'` will **always** evaluate to **TRUE**, it's the same as writing:

`($field === 'id') || true`

Comment: Wow, I really thought that was a shorthand version of writing an `or ||`.

Comment: Is there no shorthand to writing `||` in an `if` statement, like what I was attempting?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield No. BUT you can use `in_array` so you don't have to repeat the variable name twice.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield operator precedence is what comes into play here, check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$field === 'id' || 'image_id'` .
There's two sentence here:

1. `$field` is equal to `'id'`
2. `'image_id'`

The correct is:

`if($field === 'id' || $field === 'image_id')`